# Compiler doesn't say anything about property which not exist on type

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6

This interface describes the object which should contain only methods, which will return object with some `required` property.

### Expected panic from compiler when:

- add property instead of method // ok
- change required property value type // ok
- delete required property // ok
- add new property // silence

Sample

```
type Obj = {
  required: string;
}
interface ObjWithMethods {
  [req: string]: () => Obj;
}

let some: ObjWithMethods = {
  meth1: () => ({
    required: "",
    PROPERTY_WICH_NOT_EXIST_ON_TYPE: 1, // no panic from compiler
  }),
  meth2: () => ({
    required: "",
  })
}
```

How to make compiler screaming on property which is not exist on type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why doesn't the compiler complain about this extra property?

```
interface A {
    str: string;
    num: number;
}

let a1 = { str: "string", num: 0 }; // type of a1: { str: string, num: number }
let a2 = { str: "string", num: 0 } as A; // type of a2: A
let a3: A = { str: "string", num: 0 }; // type of a3: A

let a4 = { str: "string", num: 0, bool: true }; // type of a4: { str: string, num: number, bool: boolean }
let a5 = { str: "string", num: 0, bool: true } as A; // type of a5: A
console.log(a5.bool); // error
let a6: A = { str: "string", num: 0, bool: true }; // error
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20A%20%7B%0D%0A%09str%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%09num%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20a1%20%3D%20%7B%20str%3A%20%22string%22%2C%20num%3A%200%20%7D%3B%20%2F%2F%20type%20of%20a1%3A%20%7B%20str%3A%20string%2C%20num%3A%20number%20%7D%0D%0Alet%20a2%20%3D%20%7B%20str%3A%20%22string%22%2C%20num%3A%200%20%7D%20as%20A%3B%20%2F%2F%20type%20of%20a2%3A%20A%0D%0Alet%20a3%3A%20A%20%3D%20%7B%20str%3A%20%22string%22%2C%20num%3A%200%20%7D%3B%20%2F%2F%20type%20of%20a3%3A%20A%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20a4%20%3D%20%7B%20str%3A%20%22string%22%2C%20num%3A%200%2C%20bool%3A%20true%20%7D%3B%20%2F%2F%20type%20of%20a4%3A%20%7B%20str%3A%20string%2C%20num%3A%20number%2C%20bool%3A%20boolean%20%7D%0D%0Alet%20a5%20%3D%20%7B%20str%3A%20%22string%22%2C%20num%3A%200%2C%20bool%3A%20true%20%7D%20as%20A%3B%20%2F%2F%20type%20of%20a5%3A%20A%0D%0Aconsole.log(a5.bool)%3B%20%2F%2F%20error%0D%0Alet%20a6%3A%20A%20%3D%20%7B%20str%3A%20%22string%22%2C%20num%3A%200%2C%20bool%3A%20true%20%7D%3B%20%2F%2F%20error))

As you can see, with the first 3 ones (a1, a2 and a3) there's no problem because they all contain both `str` and `num`.
The error with `a6` is just as you'd expect, the compiler doesn't like it that something that is declared to be `A` contains a property that wasn't declared in the interface.
However, `a5` is completely fine, because it's cast to `A` from an object that can be `A` but also has more data.
This is fine of course because once you cast it down to `A` you no longer have access to that extra property which is why `a5.bool` raise an error.

What happens in your code is exactly what happens with `a5`, the compiler casts:

```
{
    required: "",
    PROPERTY_WICH_NOT_EXIST_ON_TYPE: 1
}
```

To `Obj`, and there's no conflict there just like there was no conflict when `a5` was cast to `A`, so this:

```
let myObj = some["meth1"]();
```

Will make `myObj` of type `Obj`, and so this:

```
console.log(myObj.PROPERTY_WICH_NOT_EXIST_ON_TYPE);
```

Results in an error, even though in reality (and in runtime) `myObj.PROPERTY_WICH_NOT_EXIST_ON_TYPE` does exist.

If you want the compiler to complain about it, then you can do something like:

```
function createMethod(value: Obj): () => Obj {
    return () => value;
}

let some: ObjWithMethods = {
    meth1: createMethod({
        required: "",
        PROPERTY_WICH_NOT_EXIST_ON_TYPE: 1 // error here
    })
}
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=type%20Obj%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20required%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20ObjWithMethods%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%5Breq%3A%20string%5D%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20Obj%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20some%3A%20ObjWithMethods%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%09meth1%3A%20createMethod(%7B%0D%0A%09%09required%3A%20%22%22%2C%0D%0A%09%09PROPERTY_WICH_NOT_EXIST_ON_TYPE%3A%201%0D%0A%09%7D)%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20createMethod(value%3A%20Obj)%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20Obj%20%7B%0D%0A%09return%20()%20%3D%3E%20value%3B%0D%0A%7D))